# how to skin an iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

im new to ipad/iphone development. what are some ways to skin an ipad app? (eg: the notes app that came with the iPad) Is there any tutorials or code samples?

Comment: Define *skin*. I am not familiar with the iPad Notes app. Are you after changing fonts, colors, backgrounds, etc based on user settings.

Comment: I think the question has to do with skinning your own apps instead of skinning Apple's pre-existing apps.

Comment: I want to change the look of the UI from the default UI in my own app. Not the built-in apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question has to do with skinning your own apps instead of skinning Apple's pre-existing apps. Assuming this:

Any buttons can be easily skinned with images. Just add the image to your XCode project. Then, select the button in Interface Builder and in the attributes inspector you can choose the image there.

You can skin other views by adding UIImageView's that cover the whole view and then moving them into the background of the layout.

My app Rith uses all of the standard controls, but everything is skinned.

Comment: what UI elements to I need to create a boxed section like the related section on this page with a 3px wide border? UILabels and what else? are UILabels clickable?

Comment: Yes, you can test UILabels for being clicked. See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539380/how-can-i-determine-if-a-uilabel-was-touched

Depending on what you're doing, you might also just use a UIWebView.