# In swift, how do I detect when a press begins and end on a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to detect when a press begins so I can perform an action while it is pressed only, stopping that action when press ends.

I know there is a pressesBegan function on UILabels but I am not sure how to use it and can't seem to find examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine if a UILabel was touched?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539380/how-can-i-determine-if-a-uilabel-was-touched)

Comment: I'm not entire sure how to recreate that with Swift though? I'll attempt to write a swift interpreted version of this answer

Comment: You should create a custom gesture recognizer and add it to the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use UILongPressGestureRecongizer.

Initialize the pressGestureRecongizer in the viewDidLoad method of your viewController and add it to the label:

```
let pressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePress:")
label.addGestureRecognizer(pressGestureRecognizer)
```

and then you define the handlePress-function

```
func handlePress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        // handle start of pressing
    }
    else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        // handle end of pressing
    }
}
```

Comment: As a test I put this code in and added two NSLogs, on in the if statement and one in the else if, but only the one in the else if (ended state) is coming to console. This is the only gesture on the label.

Comment: You are right, UITapGestureRecognizer only calls the action for the UIGestureRecongizerState.Ended. I modified the initial answer. Now it uses the UILongPressGestureRecognizer. I also improved the overall design.

Comment: Thank! this has the functionality I wanted, although it takes a moment since it's a long press now rather than a normal press.  I'll just ignore that momentary delay for now as it is pretty trivial

Comment: Just pointing out how oblivious I am: UILongPressGestureRecognizer has a minimumPressDuration, which solved that last issue haha